# How to change the foreground of the Thumb of Scrollbar in wpf?

Tags: wpf

I want to change the foreground of the Scroll bar thumb in my code.

I have applied a style which changes my thumb background, but, i wanted to change the

foreground image at run time. here is my style code for scroll bar.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="178"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="12" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="12" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Row="1" CornerRadius="2"  BorderThickness="0" >
                    <Border.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/HyperVibe;component/Images/Grey_Slider_Background.png" />
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                <RepeatButton Grid.Row="0" Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand" Content=" ^" />

                <!--IsDirectionReversed set to true draws a ScrollBar with a 
                    Track whose lowest value is at the bottom.
                    The default orientation of a ScrollBar is for the Track
                    values to decrease from top to bottom.-->
                <Track Grid.Row="1" Name="PART_Track" IsDirectionReversed="true">
                    <Track.Thumb>
                        <Thumb BorderThickness="1" DataContext="{Binding}" >
                            <Thumb.OpacityMask>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/HyperVibe;component/Images/Green%20Slider.png" />
                            </Thumb.OpacityMask>
                            <Thumb.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/HyperVibe;component/Images/Green%20Slider.png" />
                            </Thumb.Background>
                        </Thumb>
                    </Track.Thumb>
                </Track>
                <RepeatButton Grid.Row="2" Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand" Content=" v" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,
~Anup

Answer (score 1):

Try if you can load the above control template as a DynamicResource and do the following in C# code. If you load it as a static resource then you will not be able to edit the resource as it will be sealed.

```
ControlTemplate myCtrlTpl = (ControlTemplate) FindResource("MyScrollBar");
Trigger tgrIsMouseOver = new Trigger { Property = Thumb.IsMouseOverProperty, Value = true };
Trigger tgrIsMouseNotOver = new Trigger { Property = Thumb.IsMouseOverProperty, Value = false };

ImageBrush mImgBrhDefault = (Create what ever brush either imagebrush or solidcolorbrush)
ImageBrush mImgBrhHighlight = (Create what ever brush either imagebrush or solidcolorbrush)

tgrIsMouseOver.Setters.Add(new Setter(Thumb.BackgroundProperty, mImgBrhHighlight));
tgrIsMouseNotOver.Setters.Add(new Setter(Thumb.BackgroundProperty, mImgBrhDefault));
```